# How do i trigger v-on:click from jquery trigger?

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, vue.js

I am using vuejs 1.* along with jquery.But i am unable to trigger v-on:click event from jquery

```
<a id="test" v-on:click="refresh" href="#" >Cick </a>
```

and my jquery code is

`$("#test).trigger('click');` and I have tried triggering

`$("#test).trigger('v-on:click');` as well

Comment: Can't you just directly invoke `refresh` somehow?

Comment: There are some missing quotes in your sample too $("#test).   Are they like that in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but you could use it in a pinch:

When you first declare the Vue object, you could save it to variable (the global window variable is also not recommended, but it will work for this example )

```
window.myVueObj = new Vue({...});
```

Then you could trigger the `refresh()` method by calling it directly:

```
$("#test).on('click',function(){
     window.myVueObj.refresh();
});
```

Again, this is NOT a recommended way to accomplish this, it is simply a possible way to do it.

Comment: It works after page reload but when the page is loaded for the first time. It gives 'TypeError: can't convert undefined to object'

Comment: Try wrapping it in a ready function to ensure all the needed DOM elements and scripts are loaded: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                (function ($) {
        
                })(jQuery);
            });`

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery to bind a jquery event to the element in ready. you will need to filter out mouse clicks in the event handler so you dont get multiple calls to refresh. see example code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a id="test" v-on:click="refresh" href="#"> Refresh <a/>
  <p>
  <a onclick="triggerClick()"> jQuery Trigger </a>
</div>

<script>
function triggerClick() {
    console.log('triggering click from jQuery')
    $('#test').trigger('click')
}

new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    ready: function () {
        var self = this
        $(self.$el).on('click', function(evt) {
            // do not call refresh on mouse click
            if (typeof evt.originalEvent !== 'object') {
                self.refresh()
            }
        })
    },
    methods: {
        refresh: function () {
            console.log('refresh called')
        }
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be a click event that triggers refresh() you can use the instance of your component to call vm.refresh() directly.